# react native ios vibrate

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am testing the vibrate feature for ios using expo and it seems pretty straight forwared on the docs.  For some reason though I can not get the iphone to vibrate.  I can get it to console log at the time of vibrate call.  Any ideas on how I can get this working?

`app.js` toy example

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Vibration, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const startVibration = () => {
    console.log('start vibration')
    Vibration.vibrate()
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>     
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => startVibration()}>
          <Text>Vibrate Once</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>  
    </View>
  )}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#efefef',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: did you have try Vibration.vibrate([400]) ? on my previous work, I'm using that to make it works on iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into the settings on an iphone and toggled  vibrate on silent and vibrate on ring and now the vibrate works.